# Directory.Exists on a folder in Program Files fails

Tags: c#, .net, directory, exists

I simply have this bit of code.

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\My App\Sub Folder of my App\";

if(Directory.Exists(path)) {
   MessageBox.Show("It's here!");
} else {
   MessageBox.Show("Can't find it!");
}
```

Now the folder does exist and running the command:

```
explorer "C:\Program Files (x86)\My App\Sub Folder of my App\"
```

Opens up the window, yet in my code it fails to see the folder. If I had any hair I would be pulling it out.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "@" you don't need to escape the backslash character (\).

```
string path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My App\Sub Folder of my App\\";
```

My initial answer was incorrect, but I'm keeping the answer as it might be useful to others.

Comment: Actually, we shouldn't need to escape the backslash if we're using the @ string literal so I'm not sure if my answer is correct.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I'll put back the answer I deleted, and see if it's relevant.

Comment: No need to escape backslashes in verbatim string literals.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the correct solution. Another schoolboy error for myself!

Comment: What about the comments about @ string literal not needed the escapes?

Comment: @tripbrock Can you give us some more details about your changes? I would expect your original code to work as it is displayed here in SO.

Comment: This line was removed:

string path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\My App\Sub Folder of my App\";

and replaced with:


string path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My App\Sub Folder of my App\\";

This then worked.

Comment: With "\Sub Folder of my App" or "\\Sub Folder of my App".